# How to install cryptsetup 2.x to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, luks, cryptsetup

I came across with encrypted container created with LUKS2, but as a user of Ubuntu 16.04, which comes with 1.7.2, this container can't be opened. It seems I'd need a newer version of cryptsetup, 2.x.